# Passing tags data through via POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput which allows me to convert a `select` or `input` to a be a tags field. Inside of a Form, and when submitted, the data is `NULL`.

Grabbing the `.val()` or running `$("input").tagsinput('items')` displays the contents however it is not send via `POST` request. I have a number of these inputs in my form.

EDIT:
For example, I have my select here:
`<select multiple data-role="tagsinput" name="job_area" id="job_area" placeholder="Select a job area or type to insert another." class="form-control"></select>` and that is all there is to it. That is within a `<form method="POST">` with an `action` to the server (I'm using Laravel).

What would be the best way to ensure the data is send along with the form request?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please provide your code, how you send post request? you can create an pen in codepen and put the link in your question

Comment: Hi @MohammadMasoudi, thanks. I have added it. There isn't much to it. The input it within a form with post method and action. `bootstrap-tagsinput` converts it to an input.

Comment: can you more clarify your question? when you use `select` tag you get only one item in back-end? or it's completely NULL?

Comment: "job_area" has data as `NULL`. So it shows that there was an input, but the POST data has nothing there. I want to know how to pass the tags data across with the form submission.

Comment: can you try use `input` instead of `select` tag?  the `select` tag only pass one data to back-end but input tag can pass all data to back-end